# Android client to REST API server authentication

Tags: android, node.js, api, rest, express

I have a question regarding authentication methods for a REST API server using Node and Express and an Android client.

I am currently developing an app where you can register an user account. The entered password is encrypted with BCrypt and is then sent to the REST API server. After that, the user credentials are stored in a MongooseDB.

When logging in, the Android client has to authenticate somehow in order to get to the MainActivity. When entering the email address used during the registration along with the password, a query is sent to the REST API which searches for the email address. When found, it returns the entire users credentials including the encrypted password to the Android client. Here the password is then verified. If it succeeds the app will jump to the MainActivity.

Now I know this doesn't really seem like an authentication, since the server doesn't know anything about me now being authenticated nor does it care. On the other side, the received password from the REST API is encrypted.

Would it be OK to run the "authentication" as I am doing right now or should I consider doing it differently? If so, what would be an easy way to get a proper authentication up and running?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to protect any resources on the server, this method is worthless. Assume someone connects not using your app.

Comment: That is true. So what would be an easy way to implement a secure authentication?

Answer (score 1):

- Store the email and the hashed+salted pw on your server.
- When the client sends you the matching email+pw combo, return a sessionID token and a refresh token to them, also store both of these on your server.
- SessionID should then be sent with every request from the client so that the server knows it's authenticated, and who the request comes from.
- The sessionID should expire sooner (in like a day or two, compared to a week for the refresh token), after which the user gets a new one by sending the refresh token.
- If the refresh token has expired, user has to send email+pw again and get a new one of both.
- use tls 1.2 for the connection, otherwise it's really bad

Or just don't even store passwords on your server, use Google login and/or some other oauth instead, safer.